# Enforcing mvn to use Stub Project (No POM)

Tags: maven

When executing `mvn` command under a directory with no pom file, then Stub Project (No POM) will be used.

There are plugins, such as `mvn deploy:deploy-file`, which can be executed without the pom file.

When executing such plugins, I came to think I want to enforce use the Stub Project (No POM), no matter if the pom file existed under the current directory. I thought so because when I work with multi-module project, I often `cd` into each module, and do some work. I had a command history of certain `mvn` command which worked fine under Stub Project (No POM), but did not work as I expected if executed against the module's pom.

It is sort of frustrating to check if pom.xml exists or not in current directory, or to cd to some directory without pom.xml, just to execute a plugin which would work fine by ignoring the pom.

Question: is there any way to enforce `mvn` command to use the Stub Project (No POM), no matter from where the command is executed?

Comment: This `multi-module project, I often cd into each module, and do some work` is wrong. There is an command line option to maven `-pl`..which can be used for such purposes.

Comment: I know `-pl` option. The `work` does not mean `mvn` commands; rather, I meant `vim` or `rm` or `mv` or whatever for editting the files in the module. While I'm working as such way, I came to occasion where I wanted to execute certain plugins without reading any settings from pom.xml.

Comment: Why do you need to execute plugins without a project? You can define command line calls incl. parameters in your pom files...Without a pom file simply does not make sense.....

Comment: This sounds like a XY problem. You really don't want to do this. Why would you want to do this? What's your use-case?

Comment: I have a similar need in a CI/CD script, the use case being that I use mvn both as general purpose tool (to download artifacts for example) as a real build tool.